# I want to plot the route of a vector in a Lindenmayer system. How do I apply function to vector and get positions to plot?

Tags: numpy, loops, matplotlib, math, vector-graphics

This is my first question on stack overflow. I'm working on a script to plot a Lindenmayer-system. I already figured out how to do it by using the turtle package, but I would like to do it using matplotlib.pyplot
I have all turn-angles and forward-moves in a vector `np.array[move,angle,move,angle,move,angle......]`
The length of the vector is a function of the number of iteretions. For instance `L=1/3**N`, where N is the number of iterations, and L is length.
The direction of the vector is given by

```
d=np.dot(np.array([[cos(angle[i],-sin(angle[i])],sin(angle[i]),cos(angle[i])),d)
```

where the first d should be `np.array[1,0]`

The first position is `x=(0,0)`
then `x=x+L*d` and so forth
but I cant get my iterating right

I have created a couple of scripts to get my LindenmayerSystem to the vector form I wished for.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from math import cos, sin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
System="Koch"
N=1
def LindIter(System, N):

    if System == "Koch":
        LindenmayerString = "S"
        for i in range(N):
            newseq = ""
            for element in LindenmayerString:
                newseq = newseq + {"S": "SLSRSLS"}.get(element, element)
            LindenmayerString = newseq
    elif System == "Sierpinski":
        LindenmayerString = "A"
        for i in range(N):
            newseq = ""
            for element in LindenmayerString:
                newseq = newseq + {"A": "BRARB",
                                   "B": "ALBLA"}.get(element, element)
            LindenmayerString = newseq
        # replace("A",{"A":"BRARB","B":"ALBLA"},N)

    return LindenmayerString
def TurtleGraph(LindenmayerString):

    TC = ""
    if System == "Koch":
        x = np.asarray(list(LindenmayerString), dtype=object)
        x[x == "S"] = float(1/(3**N))
        x[x == "L"] = float(1/3*math.pi)
        x[x == "R"] = float(-2/3*math.pi)
        TurtleCommands = x.astype(float)
    elif System == "Sierpinski":
        x = np.asarray(list(LindenmayerString), dtype=object)
        x[x == "B"] = float(1/(2**N))
        x[x == "A"] = float(1/(2**N))
        x[x == "L"] = float(1/3*math.pi)
        x[x == "R"] = float(-1/3*math.pi)
        TurtleCommands = x.astype(float)
    return TurtleCommands
```

The operation I want now is like this for a 1-iteration Koch-system, but I would like to expand on it, so I can do more iterations:

```
vector=np.array([1/3,1/3*math.pi,1/3,-2/3*math.pi,1/3,1/3*math.pi,1/3])
N=1
Rads=TurtleCommands[1::2]
d0=np.array([1,0])
d1=np.dot(np.array([[cos(Rads[0]),-sin(Rads[0])],[sin(Rads[0]),cos(Rads[0])]]),d0)
d2=np.dot(np.array([[cos(Rads[1]),-sin(Rads[1])],[sin(Rads[1]),cos(Rads[1])]]),d1)
d3=np.dot(np.array([[cos(Rads[2]),-sin(Rads[2])],[sin(Rads[2]),cos(Rads[2])]]),d2)
x0=(0,0)
x1=x0+1/3**N*d0
x2=x1+1/3**N*d1
x3=x2+1/3**N*d2
x4=x3+1/3**N*d3
plotvals=np.append(x0,(x1,x2,x3,x4))
x=plotvals[0::2]
y=plotvals[1::2]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
[Plot of first iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w6Cx.png)
```

In many of the functions I've tried to created I got this error:

```
"    d=np.dot(np.array([[cos(Rads[i]),-sin(Rads[i])],[sin(Rads[i]),cos(Rads[i])]]),d)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"
```

I hope someone can help, and that my request are reasonable here on this wonderful forum.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that instead of creating an array of `TurtleCommands`, you can create an array of graph points right away, let's say called `Points`. Instead of the function `TurtleGraph`, I wrote the function `GraphPoints`, which implements this idea. I got the basic information about Koch and Sierpinski Lindenmayer systems from Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system).

```
import numpy as np
import math
from math import cos, sin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def LindIter(System, N):

    if System == "Koch":
        LindenmayerString = "F"
        for i in range(N):
            newseq = ""
            for element in LindenmayerString:
                newseq = newseq + {"F": "F+F-F-F+F"}.get(element, element)
            LindenmayerString = newseq
    elif System == "Sierpinski":
        LindenmayerString = "F-G-G"
        for i in range(N):
            newseq = ""
            for element in LindenmayerString:
                newseq = newseq + {"F": "F-G+F+G-F",
                                   "G": "GG"}.get(element, element)
            LindenmayerString = newseq

    return LindenmayerString

def GraphPoints(System, N, LindenmayerString):
    L = 1 / 3 ** N
    X = np.array([0, 0])
    Points = np.array([X])
    if System == "Koch":
        alpha = 0
        for i in LindenmayerString:
            if i == 'F':
                X = X + L * np.array([cos(alpha), sin(alpha)])
                Points = np.append(Points, [X], axis=0)
            elif i == '+':
                alpha += math.pi/2
            elif i == '-':
                alpha -= math.pi/2
    elif System == "Sierpinski":
        alpha = 2/3 * math.pi
        for i in LindenmayerString:
            if i == 'F':
                X = X + L * np.array([cos(alpha), sin(alpha)])
                Points = np.append(Points, [X], axis=0)
            elif i == 'G':
                X = X + L * np.array([cos(alpha), sin(alpha)])
                Points = np.append(Points, [X], axis=0)
            elif i == '+':
                alpha += 2/3 * math.pi
            elif i == '-':
                alpha -= 2/3 * math.pi
    return Points


System = "Koch" # "Sierpinski"
N = 3
LindenmayerString = LindIter(System, N)
Points = GraphPoints(System, N, LindenmayerString)
plt.plot(Points[:,0],Points[:,1])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to do what I wanted, although with some help funtctions.

```
def Get_d(TurtleCommands):
    #the [1::2] slicer takes every second argument, starting from position 1
    angles = TurtleCommands[1::2]
    #our initial direction vector
    d = np.array([1,0])
    #Settining up a list to add vectors
    dstart = [[1,0]]
    #we apply the operation for calculating subsequent d's and append them
    for theta in angles:
        d=list(np.dot(np.array([[cos(theta),-sin(theta)],[sin(theta),cos(theta)]]),d))
        dstart.append(d)
     
    return dstart
```

Then we get the points:

```
def Get_x(dstart,System,N):
    #setting first position
    xstart = (0,0)
    #initializing a list of points
    points = [(0,0)]
    #setting length scaling of vector
    if System=="Koch":
        l=1/3**N
       
    elif System=="Sierpinski":
        l=1/2**N
    
    #the points[-1] takes the last set in points
    #the [0]'s specify x coordinates and the [1]'s are y's
    for i in range(len(dstart)):
         x = points[-1][0] + l * dstart[i][0]
         y = points[-1][1] + l * dstart[i][1]
         points.append((x,y))
    
    return points
```

And can either zip or slice them :)